# jenkins git clone ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, gitlab

I'm experiencing some issues with my Jenkins running on EC2 (centos).
Jenkins version: 1.121.2
Git version: 1.8.3

I am using Gitlab as SCM. while cloning from the repository i am getting following error. It was working properly earlier, suddenly past two days it is not working. I didn't made any changes in configuration. all are same till now.

could any one help me found the solution for this. I am getting update notification from jenkins. Is it because of jenkins update ?

Credentials, git installation path and other settings are still same. Please
anyone help me to resolve this issue

```
    Building in workspace /home/centos/.jenkins/workspace/ehealth-gitlab/xxxxxx
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@gitlab.imtacsoft.com:ehealth/repositories/xxxxx.git
 > /usr/bin/git init /home/centos/.jenkins/workspace/ehealth-gitlab/xxxxxx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.imtacsoft.com:ehealth/repositories/xxxxxx.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials xxxxxxxxx
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.imtacsoft.com:ehealth/repositories/xxxxxxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.imtacsoft.com:ehealth/repositories/xxxxxxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 141:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Counting objects: 18159, done.[K
remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   1% (3/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   2% (5/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   3% (7/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   4% (10/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   5% (12/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   6% (14/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   7% (17/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   8% (19/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   9% (21/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  10% (24/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  11% (26/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  12% (28/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  13% (31/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  14% (33/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  15% (35/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  16% (37/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  17% (40/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  18% (42/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  19% (44/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  20% (47/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  21% (49/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  22% (51/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  23% (54/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  24% (56/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  25% (58/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  26% (61/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  27% (63/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  28% (65/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  29% (67/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  30% (70/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  31% (72/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  32% (74/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  33% (77/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  34% (79/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  35% (81/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  36% (84/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  37% (86/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  38% (88/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  39% (91/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  40% (93/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  41% (95/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  42% (98/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  43% (100/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  44% (102/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  45% (104/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  46% (107/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  47% (109/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  48% (111/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  49% (114/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  50% (116/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  51% (118/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  52% (121/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  53% (123/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  54% (125/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  55% (128/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  56% (130/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  57% (132/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  58% (134/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  59% (137/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  60% (139/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  61% (141/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  62% (144/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  63% (146/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  64% (148/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  65% (151/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  66% (153/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  67% (155/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  68% (158/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  69% (160/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  70% (162/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  71% (165/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  72% (167/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  73% (169/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  74% (171/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  75% (174/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  76% (176/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  77% (178/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  78% (181/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  79% (183/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  80% (185/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  81% (188/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  82% (190/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  83% (192/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  84% (195/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  85% (197/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  86% (199/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  87% (201/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  88% (204/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  89% (206/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  90% (208/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  91% (211/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  92% (213/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  93% (215/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  94% (218/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  95% (220/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  96% (222/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  97% (225/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  98% (227/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  99% (229/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (231/231)   [K
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (231/231), done.[K
Receiving objects:   0% (1/18159)   
Receiving objects:   1% (182/18159)   
Receiving objects:   2% (364/18159)   
Receiving objects:   3% (545/18159)   
Receiving objects:   4% (727/18159)   
Receiving objects:   5% (908/18159)   
Receiving objects:   6% (1090/18159)   
Receiving objects:   7% (1272/18159)   
Receiving objects:   8% (1453/18159)   
Receiving objects:   9% (1635/18159)   
Receiving objects:  10% (1816/18159)   
Receiving objects:  11% (1998/18159)   
Receiving objects:  12% (2180/18159)   
Receiving objects:  13% (2361/18159)   
Receiving objects:  14% (2543/18159)   
Receiving objects:  15% (2724/18159)   
Receiving objects:  16% (2906/18159)   
Receiving objects:  17% (3088/18159)   
Receiving objects:  18% (3269/18159)   
Receiving objects:  19% (3451/18159)   
Receiving objects:  20% (3632/18159)   
Receiving objects:  21% (3814/18159)   
Receiving objects:  22% (3995/18159)   
Receiving objects:  23% (4177/18159)   
Receiving objects:  24% (4359/18159)   
Receiving objects:  25% (4540/18159)   
Receiving objects:  26% (4722/18159)   
Receiving objects:  27% (4903/18159)   
Receiving objects:  28% (5085/18159)   
Receiving objects:  29% (5267/18159)   
Receiving objects:  30% (5448/18159)   
Receiving objects:  31% (5630/18159)   
Receiving objects:  32% (5811/18159)   
Receiving objects:  33% (5993/18159)   
Receiving objects:  34% (6175/18159)   
Receiving objects:  35% (6356/18159)   
Receiving objects:  36% (6538/18159)   
Receiving objects:  37% (6719/18159)   
Receiving objects:  38% (6901/18159)   
Receiving objects:  39% (7083/18159)   
Receiving objects:  40% (7264/18159)   
Receiving objects:  41% (7446/18159)   
Receiving objects:  42% (7627/18159)   
Receiving objects:  43% (7809/18159)   
Receiving objects:  44% (7990/18159)   
Receiving objects:  45% (8172/18159)   
Receiving objects:  46% (8354/18159)   
Receiving objects:  47% (8535/18159)   
Receiving objects:  48% (8717/18159)   
Receiving objects:  49% (8898/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  50% (9080/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  51% (9262/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  52% (9443/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  53% (9625/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  54% (9806/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  55% (9988/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  56% (10170/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  57% (10351/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  58% (10533/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  59% (10714/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  60% (10896/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
Receiving objects:  61% (11077/18159), 4.27 MiB | 8.39 MiB/s   
/home/xxxx/.jenkins/workspace/ehealth-gitlab/xxxxxx@tmp/ssh2718094864882222173.sh: line 6:  9425 Killed                  ssh -i "/home/xxxx/.jenkins/workspace/ehealth-gitlab/xxxxxxxxxx@tmp/ssh3464275883550641394.key" -l "git" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$@"

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2016)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1735)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:629)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1798)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be that `status code 141` exception indicates that no space left on device, so you need to check that first.